# How to match a top level array in json with specs2

Tags: json, scala, specs2

In specs2 you can match an array for elements like this:

```
val json = """{"products":[{"name":"shirt","price":10, "ids":["1", "2", "3"]},{"name":"shoe","price":5}]}"""

def aProductWith(name: Matcher[JsonType],  price: Matcher[JsonType]): Matcher[String] =
  /("name").andHave(name) and /("price").andHave(price)

def haveProducts(products: Matcher[String]*): Matcher[String] =
  /("products").andHave(allOf(products:_*))

json must haveProducts(
  aProductWith(name = "shirt", price = 10) and /("ids").andHave(exactly("1", "2", "3")),
  aProductWith(name = "shoe", price = 5)
)
```

(Example taken from here: http://etorreborre.github.io/specs2/guide/SPECS2-3.0/org.specs2.guide.Matchers.html)

How do I do the same thing i.e. match the contents of products if `products` is a root element in the json? What should `haveProducts` look like?

```
val json = """[{"name":"shirt","price":10, "ids":["1", "2", "3"]},{"name":"shoe","price":5}]"""
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can replace `/("products").andHave(allOf(products:_*))` with `have(allOf(products:_*))` like this:

```
val json = """[{"name":"shirt","price":10, "ids":["1", "2", "3"]},{"name":"shoe","price":5}]"""

def aProductWith(name: Matcher[JsonType],  price: Matcher[JsonType]): Matcher[String] =
  /("name").andHave(name) and /("price").andHave(price)

def haveProducts(products: Matcher[String]*): Matcher[String] = have(allOf(products:_*))

json must haveProducts(
  aProductWith(name = "shirt", price = 10) and /("ids").andHave(exactly("1", "2", "3")),
  aProductWith(name = "shoe", price = 5)
)
```